# ListFragment and onActivityCreated called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a listFragment this is my onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        utenti=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("array");
    }else{
        threadutenti= (GetUtenti) new GetUtenti(this.getActivity(), utenti).execute();
    }
```

When i rotate my device i have first savedInstanceState non null (i got it) but after onActivityCreated is called with onActivityCreated null!! why? i want get my object utenti on ListFragment and not on my activity..

Comment: *why?* - Are you sure you're not adding another fresh instance of the `Fragment` somewhere in your `Activity`?

Answer (score 10):

This can happen if you're always creating a new fragment in your *`Activity#onCreate()`* callback.
If it's true, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13306633/1233652). Your *`Fragment#onActivityCreated`* will be called twice:

- First time triggered by *`FragmentActivity#onStart`*'s call to *`mFragments.dispatchActivityCreated()`*. It will pass the saved instance.
- Second time triggered by *`FragmentActivity#onStart`*'s call to *`mFragments.execPendingActions()`*. This time without saved instance (since it is being called in response to new Fragment addition).