# Proper way to handle the lifecycle of showing and hiding fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle

In the main part of my application I have 2 fragments open at once. Only one is shown at once though.

The second fragment is being created from the onCreateView method of the first fragment, as the second fragment is used to control the first fragment.

```
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ReferenceSelectorFragment.ARG_TAB_INDEX, Tab.BOOK.position);
        mReferenceSelectorFragment.setArguments(args);
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(container.getId(), mReferenceSelectorFragment, FRAGMENT_TAGS[0])
                .hide(mReferenceSelectorFragment)
                .commit();
```

I'm properly hiding and showing the fragments using a fragment transaction:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.up_in, R.anim.up_out, R.anim.down_in, R.anim.down_out)
                .hide(ReaderFragment.this)
                .show(mReferenceSelectorFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

This works wonderfully, as expected, except for one tiny flaw. **When the application is minimized for a while and the OS closes the process, when the application is opened again, trying to restore the previous state, both fragments are restored on top of each other. Meaning both are seen at the same time on top of each other.** (This can be replicated by pressing the home button on the app, and then using DDMS to kill the running process).

I've tried everything to detect this and fix this, but it's proven very difficult to programmatically distinguish between a rotation and the application being restored after the process has been exited. **What is the proper way to deal with the lifecycle of showing and hiding fragments?**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13306633/969325

Basically you could pass a null bundle in your activities super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); or only create new fragments when they doesn't already exists. I suspect that is your issue.