# What is the strategy to use Fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have an `Activity`  which uses several `Fragment`s. One of my fragments have an `ExpandableListView` which uses an `Adapter` of self made. What is the good strategy to keep(or should I keep) and recreate/retain when screen orientation changes:

1. reference of the `Fragment` in Activity
2. `ExpandableListView` in the fragment
3. `ExpandableListView`'s states (such as collapsed/opened groups)

What I am currently doing is: reCreating the `Fragment`,`Adapter`, `ExpandableListView` inside `Fragment` each and everytime. (Not keeping states yet, but I guess I will use `SharedPreferences`).

PS: to minus voters: please elaborate what I am doing wrong. Apparently I am missing some points.

Comment: You should not to use `SharedPreferences` to do this.

Comment: Instead try `putFragment` and `getFragment/restoreFragment` see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189151/handle-fragment-on-screen-orientation-changes/20189415#20189415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have nested fragments, you can use `setRetainInstance(true)`. Or you can override  `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and save all your data, that you'll repopulate in `onCreate` / `onCreateView`. Note that the data has to be `Serializable` or `Parcelable` (preferred).

I think the downvote is because this question has been asked 10000 times :)