# How to reload the fragment activity on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I want to reload my FragmentActivity containing Fragments on orientation change. Fragment Activity containing 3 tabs and each tab containing a Fragment. My problem is that when am rotating the device, it crashes. Please help.

Code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener{
```

@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

```
    mContext = this;

    try{
        switch (selectedPosition) {
        case 0:
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        Logger.writeLOG(LOG_TAG, "@onRestart ", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchmap_main);

    try{
        mContext = this;
        mLocatorGlobal = (LocatorGlobal) getApplicationContext();
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(listTab[i])
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        Logger.writeLOG(LOG_TAG, "@onCreate ", e);
    }
}
```

@Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

```
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(tab.getPosition());
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    mZoneAdapter.refresh(locationList);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {


            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            switch (position) {
            case 0:

                MapSectionFragment mapfrag = (MapSectionFragment) MapSectionFragment.newInstance();
                    args.putInt("key",position);
                    mapfrag.setArguments(args);
                    return mapfrag;

            case 1:

                ListSectionFragment listfrag = (ListSectionFragment) ListSectionFragment.newInstance();
                    args.putInt("key",position);
                    listfrag.setArguments(args);
                    return listfrag;
}

public static class ListSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        View rootView = null;


        public static Fragment newInstance() {

              return new ListSectionFragment();
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            try{

                if (null == savedInstanceState)
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container,
                            false);
..........
}

public static class MapSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        GoogleMap map;
public static Fragment newInstance() {
              return new MapSectionFragment();
        }
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            try{
                if (null == savedInstanceState)
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_search_map, container,
                            false);
........
}
```

...............

```
}
```

Comment: post you fragment activity code..

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"` add it into manifest within your `FragmentActivity ` activity tag. It prevent your activity from reload.

Comment: <activity
             android:name=".YourActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>       use it in your manifiest

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305861/fool-proof-way-to-handle-fragment-on-orientation-change

Comment: @SathishKumar I have done this. <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        </activity>

Comment: so still your activity get reloading?

Comment: @SathishKumar yes ;(..

Comment: by adding below code its not crashing but reload only activity not fragments. when I am switching tabs then it reloads other tabs fragment.                                                    @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {


            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            switch (position) {
            case 0:

                MapSectionFragment mapfrag = (MapSectionFragment) MapSectionFragment.newInstance();
                    args.putInt("key",position);
                    mapfrag.setArguments(args);
                    return mapfrag;    
}