# TextViews lost during rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have tried a every solution I can find and am not having any luck. I have multiple dynamic textViews that change not only text but formatting such as alpha, strike-through... I can not find a reliable way to save this information through screen rotation. I am self taught and new my head is spinning...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new UIrFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.i(Tag, "onCreateView");
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ImageView background = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.background);
        background.setImageResource(R.drawable.starrynightblurry);
        setupKeyBoard(); // multiple textViews get set up here. Want to save this 
        setupGame();// same here

    }
```

Comment: With screen rotation you mean changing from portrait to landscape screen orientation?

Comment: yes. Screen orientation change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when using **setRetainInstance(true)**, the Bundle for onRestoreInstanceState is null.

store text views in

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //store here
}
```

Restore text view from here

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);        
    // restore here
}
```

hope this helps you

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState does not work inside a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in **activity_main.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
```

Comment: My landscape layout will not be used if I do this?

Comment: landscape layout will not be used ??

Comment: I thought this would prevent screen rotation. It didn't but it also didn't save the state of my textViews.

Comment: to prevent screen rotation add android:screenOrientation="portrait" in ur  AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

either fix screen orientation to either landscape or portrait in your **AndroidManifest.xml** like this:

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or handle the configChanges like this:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
```

should be added as an attribute of the `<activity>` tag in the manifest. The `configChanges` is used to specify configuration changes that the activity will handle itself.

Edit: for handling config changes in Fragments, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305861/fool-proof-way-to-handle-fragment-on-orientation-change).

Comment: I want the rotation so the first option is no good. I tried the second but the textViews are still reset.

Comment: really? Are you sure you have added it to the correct activity? Maybe also clean project.

Comment: I copied that code and placed directly under the android:name tag in the <activity.

Comment: I see. I think it is because the views are in a Fragment. Let me remember how configChanges were handled with Fragments...

Comment: Try the first answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305861/fool-proof-way-to-handle-fragment-on-orientation-change

Comment: @user3322233 did handling config changes in fragments solve your problem in the end?

Comment: Sort of I am now getting a saved state. I think I need to research how to save the multiple (30+) Textviews in the out state. Not just the text but the formatting. Thanks for the help

Comment: I ended up using onSavedInstantState. I just had to properly learn how to handle fragments. Thank you for the direction.