# Turn off auto rotation in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation

I have a PictureFragment which I use to show a picture in fullscreen when selecting it from my thumbnail. It works fine, but when I rotate my smartphone, the picture also rotates and gets scaled very ugly sothat its height is now its actual width and so on. How can I turn off the rotation for this fragment? I've read always how to do it for a whole activity but for the rest of the activity this runs in I want to keep the auto rotation. Or, if this is also easy possible, how can I manage to scale the picture sensefully on rotation to keep its aspect ratio?

Comment: Better to set `Orientation` to your `Activity`.

Comment: I have only one activtiy and switch between screens via fragmentmanager. And why do I get thumbs down for this question?

Comment: I think this may answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305861/fool-proof-way-to-handle-fragment-on-orientation-change

Comment: thank you. another question: is it senceful to use very less activities (one or two) and do a lot of screenchanging stuff with the fragment manager? Or is it better to use an activity for every screen?

Comment: @MD it's a bit old, but what if you only use one activity? or is that bad in general.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In your `Fragment` call inside `onResume` to lock to portrait:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

then in `onPause` to unlock orientation:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

OBS! For the sake, use `if(getActivity != null)` before using this methods.

Comment: I found myself in an endless activity restart loop if I navigate from FragmentA (IN landscape mode) to FragmentB (containing portait lock logic from top)

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution using Googles Navigation Conponents:

In your Activity:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.fragmentB) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        } else if (requestedOrientation != ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR
        }
    }
```

This logic would lock the screen orientation of "fragmentB" (Id resource from your navigation graph) to portrait.

`navController` is an instance of `androidx.navigation.NavController`

Answer (score 0):

Add in manifest

**android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"**

add in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (getActivity() != null) {          
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }       
}
```

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

 should not be used. It's bad practice