# How can I handle Orientation change so Fragment doesn't load?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

When an `EditText` line in the UI gains focus, a `DatePickerFragment` launches for the user to enter a date.

On orientation change, if the `EditText` line has focus and a previously entered date (so that `length() > 0`) I don't want the fragment to automatically show.

Is there a way to modify or add code so that if the Activity is newly created and the `EditText` line has focus it won't automatically launch the  `DatePickerFragment`?

Would it be a good idea to do something in `onResume()`?

Or do something with `savedInstanceState()` and `!=null`?

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
...
    if (hasFocus && (EditText.getText().length() == 0)) {
       DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
       newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
    else if (hasFocus && (EditText.getText().length() > 0)) {
       ...
       DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
       newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
 }
});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use viewPager or just add fragment into your activity? One way is to save data that you want to maintain on rotation into `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` bundle and then restore that data inside onCreate using

```
 if(savedInstanceState != null) {
   //get your data
 }
```

or simply add your fragment only when the activity was loaded (not reloaded after device rotation)

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) 
{
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Anyways you should definitely check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305861/fool-proof-way-to-handle-fragment-on-orientation-change) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474104/android-fragment-lifecycle-over-orientation-changes) questons, they might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, just adding fragment in the activity.  I will edit above to show the Activity.

Comment: Ok, so I am using DatePickerDialog so show(getSupportFragmentManager) does the fragmenttransactions.  The "if(savedInstanceState == null)" line can also be interpreted as don't add the fragment when the savedInstanceSate is not null, which is true after device rotation?

Comment: yes, even if you don't save any data to outState bundle, savedInstenceState will be not null if device rotation is the case

Comment: Excellent, that works.  Also, since I have the length test "if (hasFocus && (EditText.getText().length() == 0))" do I later need to explicitly include "length()>0" as shown above or will that always be the case if length is not ==0 so therefore length>0 would not be needed?

Comment: if you want to create fragment only if it was device rotation AND the edit text is not empty, then you should use it again

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, instead of using a `OnFocusChangeListener` I would use a `OnClickListener` to show the fragment whenever `EditText` is clicked, and make `EditText` non-focusable.

For the orientation change, it is worth noting that you can prevent configuration changes taking effect on an activity by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` on the manifest to the related activity. Not sure if this helps in your case though, but you can take a look.

Comment: adding android:configChanges="orientation" is good to prevent activity from restart. but it won't work if you only need to prevent fragment from re-creation, not the whole activity

Comment: Thanks for your note.  But some users will have a keyboard where they can use the tab key rather than a mouseclick on the EditText.  If I make non-focusable then user won't be able to move focus onto the EditText using their tab key.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my Activity has OnClickListener code too, as you recommended.  Thanks!