# Disable other fragments in auto rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, autorotate

i have an app with various fragments and the problem is when the phone rotates, the app displays other fragments from the begining. it does not close the current fragments but looks like layers on top of each other. any help i'd be grateful. thanks

Comment: do you want that other fragment should be in portrait only ?

Comment: no i think rotation would be good for my app. how would i do that, turn off rotatin

Comment: okay it got. it think your app do not retain to same state when you rotate it changes fragment on rotate ?

Comment: If you are adding multiple fragments to your activity then when you rotate your phone , activity gets re created and all your fragments get displayed again . You have to store the current fragment at the time of rotation and display it back when rotated

Comment: check my answer below it will solve your issue.

Comment: yeah @mishra thats the problem how do i do that

Comment: please accept answer if it is helpfull. @vinstar

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add in your AndroidManifest

```
     <Activity 
        ....
        ....
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for a **savedInstanceState**, and if it exists, don't re-create your fragments. just check if is null or not

as shown below

```
    @Override        
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                 // Do your oncreate because there is no bundle   
            }else{
        // Do that needs to be done even if there is a saved instance, or do nothing
    }
    }
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13306633/2826147) for more detail.

Comment: okay so i put ALL my activity code in the if, then i do nothing in the else, is that it?

Comment: no, you need to maintain state of old fragment with super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);. So maybe set tag and find the fragment if it exist, or pass null bundle to super. find out more http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: was this helpfull  ? @vinstar