# lost fragment when orientation changed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had a problem when I change orientation of fragment.
I had only one activity with some fragments.
Activity run fragment1 => fragment1 run fragment 2
So when I change orientation of fragment 2, I found the activty.
what I did :

I add this line to all the fragments :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain this fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);
        }
```

and in activity onCreate
I did this :

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentLayout);
    findViewById(R.id.fragmentLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Map<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
    // Check if we are restoring the activity from an orientation change
    // for example
    if (map == null || map.isEmpty()) {
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getInt("CategoryId") >0 ) {

            fragment2 itemsFragment = new fragment2();

            fragment2.setArguments(extras);

            SplashActivity.this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, itemsFragment).addToBackStack("fragment2").commit();
        }
    }
```

so my question, how I can change orientation of fragment 2 and stay in fragment2 ?

Comment: Did you added  android:configChanges="orientation" under Activity in Manifest?

Comment: Yes I added it but the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13306633/2826147