# Black space at the bottom with targetSdkVersion 22 on a device with Android 11

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-appcompat, targetsdkversion

Following bug occurs on a fairly new Motorola Defy with Android 11:

I have a weird black bottom bar in my app when my `targetSdkVersion` is 22 which disappears if I set 24 as `targetSdkVersion`.

[image: Bug occurs on Motorola Defy with ndroid 11]

The bug does not appear on my Motorola E2 with Android 5.

I'd wish to stay at `targetSdkVersion` 22 for valid reasons. The app will run on a very low number of known devices at our customer. The phone is locked up in some sort of a kiosk mode. `targetSdkVersion` 22 doesn't enforce `RuntimePermissions` which makes is perfect for the use as kiosk app.

Here's the stripped down `build.gradle (:app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        //...
        minSdkVersion 17
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 140
        versionName "1.4.0 in dev " + new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    }
}

dependencies {

    //We don't plan to switch to AndroidX with our legacy Android apps that were written around API level 19
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Here's the stripped down `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxxxxxxxx">

    <application
        android:name="xxxxx.xxxxApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.PresetActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's the stripped down `styles.xml` (I only have one `styles.xml`):

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>

</resources>
```

Stripped down activity code:

```
package xxxxxxxxxxx.ui.activity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import xxxxxxxxx.ui.fragment.PresetFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PresetActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);

        // Add fragment the correct way
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474104/android-fragment-lifecycle-over-orientation-changes

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.FragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer,
                    new PresetFragment());

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_container.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/color_background"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/status_bar_fragment"
        class="xxx.ui.fragment.StatusBarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_status_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status_bar_fragment"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/status_bar_fragment"></FrameLayout>
        
        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system assumes that your application cannot handle non standard aspect ratio and uses a 16:9 letterbox.

This can be controlled with [resizeableActivity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#resizeableActivity) :

```
<activity
    ....
    android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

If you don't set it, the default value is true if you target API 24 or greater, and false otherwise.

Comment: Thx! You made my day :) Actually `<application ... android:resizeableActivity="true">` is the better place. Didn't want to set it in every single `<activity>`-tag.

Comment: I didn't know that you could set it globally, Thanks